# Getting the actual UITableViewCell for a tapped UITableView created using the Storyboard.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created a `UITableView` in my application.  I've Created a custom `UITableViewCell` called `VideoCell` which contains a `UIWebview`, a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

The `UIWebView` is the same size as the `UIImageView` and  in the same location, but behind the `UIImageView`.  I want to hide the `UILabel` and the `UIIMageView` when I tap the cell, so that the `UIWebView` is revealed.

The `VideoCell` has a ReuseIdentifier set in the storyboard editor which I use for dequeing the `VideoCell` from in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VideoCell";
    VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    ...

    return cell;
}
```

How can I get a reference to the actual cell that I tap in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in order to visibly change the properties?

I've tried just dequing with the same arguments

```
VideoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Which returns me a VideoCell, but with no fields set up

I've also tried calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but that returns me a new instance of the VideoCell with the correct fields set up, and this is not the one that is currently displayed.

Comment: Would love to know why this was downvoted :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VideoCell *cell = (VideoCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Don't call the **data source** method present in **ViewController**, call the method on actual instance of your `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead of

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

is the correct way to get the instance of the cell. If you are unable to retrieve the exact cell you want in this way, it just means that your implementation in that method is wrong.

Comment: Are you able identify what it is that's wrong with my cellForRowAtIndexPath method that I posted in the question?

Comment: @MattFellows You haven't given the full code of that method. I have seen few people creating new cell every time without checking weather its nil or not. That's the reason I asked to check your code.

Comment: Thanks @rajesh but that is all the relevant code - Using iOS 7's storyboard, you can't get a nil cell from dequeing.  The only code missing is where I'm setting properties on the subviews of the cell.  For what it's worth: The reason my cellForRowAtIndexPath was not correct was because I was using the method from the ViewController, not the Table.